# How to use Jquery/Ajax with asp.net MVC 4 with partial view and action with model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to both asp.net MVC and JQuery so be gentle.

I am trying to use a HTTP Post to update my contact form, used to send an email, using AJAX. I have seen lots of posts but what I want seems specific and I cant seem to find anything relevant.

The down low: I have a layout page which has the header, renders the body and has my footer in. My footer contains the form I want to submit. I want to submit this form without refreshing the whole page. The layout page:

```
    <div id="footer">

        @{Html.RenderAction("Footer", "Basic");}

    </div>

<p id="p"></p>
```

I have a model for this form to send an email.

```
namespace SimpleMemberShip.Models
{
    public class EmailModel
    {


        [Required, Display(Name = "Your name")]
        public string FromName { get; set; }
        [Required, Display(Name = "Your email"), EmailAddress]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The email address entered is not valid")]
        public string FromEmail { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }

}
```

The footer:

```
 <h2> footer yo !</h2>

@Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Me!</legend>

        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromEmail)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromEmail)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message)
            </li>
        </ol>

        <button id="submit"> Submit </button>

</fieldset>
```

controller:

```
      [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Footer()
    {

        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml");


    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Footer(EmailModel model)
    {

         return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml"); 
    }
```

I want to use the model validation and everything to be the same or similar as if the form was posted normally through the server.

**Edit: 
My new code, which works great! but it only works once, when the button is clicked again nothing happens. Anyone know why?**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


$("#submit").click(function () {

    $("#footer").html();
        var url = '@Url.Action("Footer", "Basic")';
        $.post(url, { FromName: $("[name=FromName]").val(), FromEmail: $("  [name=FromEmail]").val(), Message: $("[name=Message]").val() }, function (data)    {

             $("#footer").html(data);

        });

        var name = $("[name=FromName]").val();
        $("#p").text(name);

    });

</script>
```

**new Edit:**

did some research and using

```
$("#submit").live("click",function () {
```

instead of

```
 $("#submit").click(function () {
```

seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Remove the attribute `ChildActionOnly` from the second method (the post method) you have there. It prevents post action from getting to it.

Comment: ok, two things. 1. you need to differentiate in your Footer Action the difference between a normal http post and an ajax post. this will allow you to return either a json result, or the partial view. You can do this by using the method `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())` 2. create a clientside template to render the json results from the controller. I apologize that I don't add this as a proper answer - i'm in transit and given the level of zealous downvoting in recent years, would hate to put a comma in the wrong place :). will address this when I get back to base tmro (if not resolved by then)

Comment: Note also you can simplify your `$.post()` to `$.post(url, $('form').serialize(), function(data) { ..` Apart from the comments above, you also need to cancel the default submit (or better, make it a normal button - `<button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>`) so you do not make both a normal submit and an ajax submit.

Comment: But since you already have the `_Footer` partial in you view, why does your POST method return another identical copy of it? Its not clear what you mean by _// what the hell do i do_ - what do you want to do? - display a success or error message?

Comment: @DPac thank you for that, now I got rid of that it seems to be working as intended!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$("#submit").live("click",function () {
    $('.validation-summary-errors').remove();
        var url = '@Url.Action("Footer", "Basic")';
        $.post(url, { FromName: $("[name=FromName]").val(), FromEmail: $("[name=FromEmail]").val(), Message: $("[name=Message]").val() }, function (data) {

            $("#footer").html(data);

        });


    });

</script>
```

ended up with this but will try the "serialize()" option next time.
controller was changed to this without the [ChildActionOnly] and works perfect now

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Footer(EmailModel model)
    {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml");
    }
```

Thank you everyone that helped!

Answer (score -1):

Change the `[ChildActionOnly]` to `[HttpGet]` in the controller
You can pass model data to controller by doing the following steps
1. Get the `input` values on click of submit and sent to the `Footer` action in controller

```
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var FromEmailValue = $('#FromEmail').val();
        var FromNameValue = $('#FromName').val();
        var MessageValue = $('#Message').val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("Footer", "Basic")';
        $.ajax({
             url: urlmodel,
            data: { FromName: FromNameValue, FromEmail: FromEmailValue, Message: MessageValue},
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                do something here
            }
            error: function (reponse) {
                do something here
            }
        });
    });
```

2. In the controller

``

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Footer()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml");
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Footer(string FromName = "", string FromEmail = "", string Message = "")
    {
        //for ajax request
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            do your stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello! Not really what I wanted but thank you anyway!

Comment: i can't understand your question. its little confusing

Comment: Yeah sorry that's probably my bad, sorry! I did find it useful though, especially just the simple things like adding an ID to the input fields.

Comment: if you want to know any thing just ask bro

Comment: _especially just the simple things like adding an ID to the input fields_? The `id` attributes are already added by the Html Helper - using `new { @id="FromEmail" }` to add replace the `id` with exactly the same `id` is pointless.